# Generic standalone python script for use in any web framework

Tags: python, django, web

I have a Django view in one of my websites, with logic that can be made so that it's separated from the rest of the code.

I would like to provide this logic/functionality to third-party websites, regardless of the Python framework they're using. It needs to be accessible from a URL, say `www.example.com/customurlprovidedbyme` and needs access to request/server params.

**Is there a way in Python to provide a generic view/page to websites without having to customize implementation for each framework?**

It is necessary that the script is executed by their servers and served from their domains. The only solution I see so far is to customize it for the major frameworks.

I'm thinking of a python module, but never made so so I don't know if I can make it so that a URL is browsable from that module. As you can see, my Python knowledge is limited.

I also have it in PHP and in that case I just provide a PHP file, they dump it on their doc root.

Comment: Instead of making it depend on request/server params, why don't you make it an ordinary function that accepts the parameters it needs (i.e., as ordinary Python function arguments)?  Users of frameworks can then extract the relevant parameters from the request themselves and pass them to your function.

Comment: That would be indeed a way, I'm just looking to make it as hands off as possible for these sites, as they are bigger than average and any programming task, from my experience, takes a long time to get implemented on their side. The view also manipulates response headers, so another thing to worry about. Thank you for your input.

Comment: take by example 3 web frameworks, Django, Flask and Pyramid, do you see that these ones have different ways to route urls? different ways to call controllers/views-in-Django-parlance ? different ways to pass parameters to the method or class used ? is more easy to think in a generic function/method for your logic, put in a libs.py file to be used (as library) and call this from your views/controllers in different web frameworks.

Comment: Execute code from outside of your app could lead to some vulnerabilities on their part. I wouldn't access a service that requires me executing arbitrary code. It may be better to expose a service that performs the required operations and returns the result, using some API. That way you would have something that is not language dependent and easier to use.

Comment: If the case is that they absolutely need the code, you can put that on a different file and document it's usage. Then you can distribute it.

Comment: @cdvv7788 well it wouldn't be arbitrary, they would be able to see and analyze it :) I'ts only about 60 lines. I guess I'm going to have to use a mix of the advice received here. Thank you all for your help